# What The Equivalent Of Oracle Schema Isolation In AzureSQL And PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, oracle, azure-sql-database

The database choices for my new application are Azure SQL and PostgreSQL.
It is SaaS and each client will need to be isolated from each other for security reasons.
This has to be done at the infrastructure level so an application mistake can't expose other client data.

If I was using Oracle I would do the following:

- Single database with an individual schema for each client
- Each client uses its own copy of the application with its own connection string

This makes it simple from an application point of view as it doesn't have to consider being multi-tenant.
This also means the schema can be backed up and loaded separately from the rest of the database.

What is the equivalent of this data isolation model in Azure SQL and PostgreSQL?

Comment: Both Azure SQL and PostgreSQL support `create schema ... `. But you might need to explore exactly what *can't have access to each others data* means in your context.

Answer (score 4):

> Single database with an individual schema for each client

Schema-per-client is not real not infrastructure isolation; it's weaker, and available on both PostgreSQL and Azure SQL Database.  But that doesn't give you per-client backups, per-client scaling, etc.  Even Oracle supports database-per-client via [Pluggable Databases](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/cdbovrvw.htm#CNCPT89234) since Oracle 12.

But both SQL Server and PostgreSQL have always supported multiple databases per instance, so the recommended multi-tenant architecture is to have a separate database for each client.  This is especially so in Azure where the servers, storage, and backups are managed for you.

For instance see [Multitenancy and Azure SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/guide/multitenant/service/sql-database)